# creating unique page title slugs php

Tags: php, mysql, unique, slug

I have a function for creating unique slug for a page title. It checks if the slug is available in the pages table then creates a unique slug by adding a '-int' accordingly. The function works fine for the first three entries eg for 'test slug' entered three time will create 'test-slug-1', 'test-slug-2' and 'test-slug-3'. Then after that I get an error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" for the fourth entry. There should be some problem with the logic, can anyone help me find it please.Below is the code:

```
function createSlug($title, $table_name, $field_name) {

global $db_connect;

$slug = preg_replace("/-$/","",preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', "-", strtolower($title)));

$counter = 1;

do{

  $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name  = '".$slug."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));


  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      $count = strrchr($slug , "-"); 
      $count = str_replace("-", "", $count);
      if($count > 0){

          $length = count($count) + 1;
          $newSlug = str_replace(strrchr($slug , "-"), '',$slug);
          $slug = $newSlug.'-'.$length;

          $count++;

      }else{
          $slug = $slug.'-'.$counter;
      }  

  }

  $counter++; 
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

}while(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0);

return $slug;
```

}

Comment: Instead of repeatedly hitting the database, you can just use LIKE to return all matching results then if the number of results is greater than 0 append the count of the number of the results to the slug.

Comment: Append count+1 is not the best idea as a record #3 could have been deleted but record 4 was not, that leaves 3 records, the next one you add is going to conflict

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use a single query to do all the heavy lifting for you...

```
$slug = preg_replace("/-$/","",preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', "-", strtolower($title)));

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumHits FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name  LIKE '$slug%'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$numHits = $row['NumHits'];

return ($numHits > 0) ? ($slug . '-' . $numHits) : $slug;
```

Comment: Much Thanks, that works perfect. Thanks to everyone who contributed, you have all helped in some way. Much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted as this turned into a huge list of code-heavy answers!

Comment: bad example. it will add double slugs after a row has been deleted

Comment: I dont thik this is not good idea. assume there is slug_2 in a 2nd row, but it never check for it. if there is same title used for 3 times there will be 1 title and 2 title_2 s

Comment: This is not working when below case.
1) My post -> my-post
2) My post -> my-post-1
3) My -> my-3 

This conversion is going to wrong.

Answer (score 33):

Just hit the database once, grab everything at once, chances are that's the biggest bottleneck.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name  LIKE '".$slug."%'";
```

Then put your results in an array (let's say `$slugs`)

```
//we only bother doing this if there is a conflicting slug already
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0 && in_array($slug, $slugs)){
    $max = 0;

    //keep incrementing $max until a space is found
    while(in_array( ($slug . '-' . ++$max ), $slugs) );

    //update $slug with the appendage
    $slug .= '-' . $max;
}
```

We use the `in_array()` checks as if the slug was `my-slug` the `LIKE` would also return rows such as

```
my-slug-is-awesome
my-slug-is-awesome-1
my-slug-rules
```

etc which would cause issues, the `in_array()` checks ensure that we are only checking against the exact slug that was entered.

## Why don't we just count the results and +1?

This is because if you had multiple results, and deleted a few, your next slug could well conflict.

E.g.

```
my-slug
my-slug-2
my-slug-3
my-slug-4
my-slug-5
```

Delete -3 and -5 leaves us with

```
my-slug
my-slug-2
my-slug-4
```

So, that gives us 3 results, the next insert would be `my-slug-4` which already exists.

## Why don't we just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`?

We can't just do an `order by` in the query because <sup>the lack of</sup> natural sorting would make `my-slug-10` rank lower than `my-slug-4` as it compares character by character and `4` is higher than `1`

E.g.

```
m = m
y = y
- = -
s = s
l = l
u = u
g = g
- = -
4 > 1 !!!
  < 0 (But the previous number was higher, so from here onwards is not compared)
```

Comment: You can order by length of field, then by field itself to achieve natural sorting :) sort of.

Comment: This is not working when below case.
1) My post -> my-post
2) My post -> my-post-1
3) My -> my-3 

This conversion is going to wrong.

Comment: Hello, Hailwood how you going? could you take a look in my answer its similar than that one.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906354/unique-profile-slug-with-php-and-pdo Thank you soo much

Answer (score 3):

You can just select slug with the biggest number and increase it with 1:

```
$query = "SELECT $field_name FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name LIKE '".$slug."-[0-9]*' ORDER BY $field_name DESC LIMIT 1";
```

`[0-9]*` in query means any count of numbers.

This query will select row with `$slug` at start and the bigest number.

After that you can parse result get number and increase it.

In this case you will have only one query and lot of unused performance.

**UPDATE**

This will not work, because `slug-8` will be "bigger" than `slug-11`. But no idea how to fix it. maybe `ORDER BY`id`DESC` ?

**UPDATE 2**

Query can be ordered by length too and it will work right. Thanks to Jack:

```
$query = "SELECT $field_name FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name LIKE '".$slug."-[0-9]*' ORDER BY LENGTH($field_name), $field_name DESC LIMIT 1";
```

**UPDATE 3**

Also added check for original slug. Thanks to Hailwood.

```
$query = "SELECT $field_name FROM $table_name WHERE $field_name = '".$slug."' OR $field_name LIKE '".$slug."-[0-9]*' ORDER BY LENGTH($field_name), $field_name DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY LENGTH($field_name) DESC, $field_name DESC`?

Comment: @Jack hmm, probably will work. Thanks, will update my answer.

Comment: Although this doesn't check for the existence of the original slug (aka no `-int`) so all slugs will end up having a `-int`

Comment: Two more things, 1) you have two sets or ORDER BY, 2) you want OR not AND, no string could ever be itself and itself + `-[digit]`

Comment: @Hailwood made more updates on this answer than in my rest answers :)

Comment: Actually, I had to make a couple changes to get this to work for me:
`$query = "SELECT $field_name FROM $table_name WHERE $field_name = '".$slug."' OR $field_name REGEXP '".$slug."-[0-9]*' ORDER BY LENGTH($field_name) DESC, $field_name DESC LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a slug and leave the rest of the job that involves indexing to MySQL. Here is a `slugify` function ( it is a slightly modified version used by Symfony framework ).

```
function slugify( $text ) {
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);  
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $text);   
    $text = strtolower(trim($text));
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    return empty($text) ? substr( md5( time() ), 0, 8 ) : $text;
}
```

And the MySQL part can be solved with [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) ( change the table and column names ).

```
BEGIN
     declare original_slug varchar(255);
     declare slug_counter int;
     set original_slug = new.slug;
     set slug_counter = 1;
     while exists (select true from post where slug = new.slug) do
        set new.slug = concat(original_slug, '-', slug_counter); 
        set slug_counter = slug_counter + 1;
     end while;
END
```

[MySQL Insert row, on duplicate: add suffix and re-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219340/mysql-insert-row-on-duplicate-add-suffix-and-re-insert)

Comment: Combining this with @Narek's solution is probably the most elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

For the one part I would create an object that is dealing with the part creating the slug and handling the number:

```
// generate new slug:
$slug = new NumberedSlug('Creating Unique Page Title Slugs in PHP');
echo $slug, "\n", $slug->increase(), "\n";

// read existing slug:
$slug = new NumberedSlug('creating-unique-page-title-slugs-in-php-44');
echo $slug->getNumber(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
creating-unique-page-title-slugs-in-php
creating-unique-page-title-slugs-in-php-1
44
```

For the other part, the database, this already greatly simplifies your code (please double check, I've done this quick). Also see how you can benefit from the Mysqli object you actually have (but not use as is):

```
function createSlug($title, $table_name, $field_name, Mysqli $mysqli = NULL)
{
    $mysqli || $mysqli = $GLOBALS['db_connect'];

    $slug = new NumberedSlug($title);

    do
    {
        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name  = '" . $slug . "'";

        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var_export($mysqli->error_list, true));
        }

        if ($result->num_rows) {
            $slug->increase();
        }

    } while ($result->num_rows);

    return $slug;
}
```

But as others have already written you should first get all slugs that are numbered at once from the database and then pick a unique one if necessary. This will reduce the number of database calls. Also the code is much more compact:

```
function createSlug2($title, $table_name, $field_name, Mysqli $mysqli = NULL)
{
    $mysqli || $mysqli = $GLOBALS['db_connect'];

    $slug = new NumberedSlug($title);

    $query = "SELECT $field_name FROM $table_name WHERE $field_name LIKE '$slug-_%'";

    if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(var_export($mysqli->error_list, true));
    }

    $existing = array_flip(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result->fetch_all()));

    $slug->increase();

    while (isset($existing[$slug])) 
    {
        $slug->increase();
    }

    return $slug;
}
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/private/3c8c6b27c5414d)

Comment: Whoops, I broke it :D http://eval.in/private/2759b55f18fd2f There is nothing to stop your users from manually creating a page with the slugs `'php-5', 'php-4', 'php-3', 'php-1'` Which causes the code to fall over as it is expecting the numbers to be ordered ascendingly in the array, which nothing says they have to be.

Comment: @Hailwood: oh right. just array_merge the result via call_user_func_array and then sort with natsort. -- http://eval.in/private/3c8c6b27c5414d -- or even just use `in_array` or `array_flip` and `isset`

Comment: I think I must be tired, I'm a nit picking bastard tonight ;)

Comment: I'll upvote, but I broke it again :D http://eval.in/private/03780cbbf5d041 If `$slug-[digit]` exists, even if just `$slug` doesn't it's going to throw it's toys and assume that `$slug` is taken :D

Comment: I did understood OP wanted to have slugs numbered, always, that's also why I $slug->increase() before the check once to give it that number. If you don't want that, just remove the first increase.

Comment: Not one mentioned the length a slug can be. if a database field can store 255 bytes and the slug is > 254 bytes, the added number will not be stored into the database which results again in a slug that did exist before.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't fully satisfied with the answers, so I came up with a slightly different approach.

```
(SELECT CONCAT({$slug}, '-', counter) FROM (
  SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS counter, ev.*
  FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(slug, {$slug}-, '') AS remainder
    FROM products, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
    WHERE slug LIKE '{$slug}%'
  ) ev
  ORDER BY LENGTH(remainder), remainder
) sr
WHERE counter <> remainder)
LIMIT 1
```

What this basically does, it checks all the existing values in the DB that are similar to the new slug, and matches it against the row number to check for gaps, and if none is found, it uses the maximum number that's generated by the first identical slug that gets pushed to the end (note: we replace `slug-` and not `slug`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE  $field_name  LIKE '".$slug."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
//EDITED BASED ON COMMENT SUGGESTIONS
//create array of all matching slug names currently in database
$slugs = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $slugs[] = $row['field_name'];
}
//test if slug is in database, append - '1,2,..n' until available slug is found
if(in_array($slug, $slugs)){
    $count = 1;
    do{
       $testSlug = $slug . '-' . $count;
       $count++;
    } while(in_array($testSlug, $slugs));
    $slug = $testSlug;
}
//insert slug
```

You should be able to do this in a single database call with the LIKE keyword that will reduce your execution time.

Comment: This would break if you had slug "test-slug-1" and tried to enter slug "test"

Comment: what about if you have rows `slug-1`, `slug-3`, `slug-5` and adding one more?

Comment: Good suggestions, will revise or defer to Hailwoods solution that submitted at a similar time

Comment: Shouldn't this be `while(in_arr...` instead of `while(!in_arr...`? otherwise you're looping until an item is found in the array? Although I do like this solution!

Comment: Also, by modifying $slug each loop, instead of incrementing the int you are just creating e.g. `$slug-1-2-3-4-5`

Comment: You are correct again.. Modified code to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Fbeen/UniqueSlugBundle](https://github.com/Fbeen/UniqueSlugBundle). This Bundle is lightweight and does what it needs to do.