# Unique Slug Issue Auto Increment

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have slugs formatted like `my-cool-slug` however I need to auto increment some to make a similar slug unique such as `my-cool-slug-2` -3, -4 etc.  I am following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972027/635027 to do this but I ran into an issue.

The slug stops at a -1 count when inserting into MySQL and keeps entering that over an over instead of increment to the next integer when finding a duplicate. Below is my query and associated lines.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$slug = 'my-cool-slug';

$slug_query = "SELECT * FROM pv_events WHERE event_slug LIKE '".$slug."%'";
$slug_result = mysqli_query($conn,$slug_query);
$slugs = mysqli_fetch_array($slug_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($slug_result) !== 0 && in_array($slug, $slugs)){
        $max = 0;

        //keep incrementing $max until a space is found
        while(in_array( ($slug . '-' . ++$max ), $slugs) );

        //update $slug with the appendage
        $slug .= '-' . $max;
    }
```

Comment: The while statement is correct, so the issue is coming from the `mysqli_fetch_array` is it returning the results you're expecting?

Comment: No, as Devon mentions below, it is only returning the first result using `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: i assume your events table has an `id` field. why not just append the `id` to the slug and be done with unnecessary shenanigans.

Comment: @pala_ Great idea- thanks.  I think you're right that I don't need to over complicate this.  Just search the DB for common slug, if exists then it appends the row id. Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)** selects the next row, not the entire result set, so **$slugs** would only contain the first result.

Secondly, if you want to start with 2, it would make sense to set **$max** to 1, not 0.  The first iteration of your while, 1 will be added.

Comment: So I should be using a while and placing results into an array?  ` while($row = $slug_result->fetch_array()) {
  $slugs[] = $row;
 }`

Comment: Well I would be doing this differently to begin with.  There are various ways that this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just select "event_slug" instead "*"

   $slug_query =  "SELECT event_slug FROM pv_events WHERE event_slug LIKE '".$slug."%'";
2. Use mysqli_fetch_all

   $slugs = mysqli_fetch_all($slug_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);