# Add number to duplicate key in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get a solution to add a number to a string on insert to column in database if the string is duplicated.

For example, i have a table test with the unique column name. I want to, when running this code

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (example)
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (example)
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (example)
```

The values inserted turn out

1. example
2. example-1
3. example-2

Is it possible to do this directly on the database or is it better to do it on the api (Node.JS) that connects to the database?

Comment: Here is probably the rigth answer : [MySQL Insert row, on duplicate: add suffix and re-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219340/mysql-insert-row-on-duplicate-add-suffix-and-re-insert) It is an insertion with an addittion of a number to its value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?